# How can I replace a Label for an image just with css3?

Tags: css

I have an code like

```
<ul id="payment-methods">
  <li>
    <input class="payment-method" id="gateway_4063663" name="gateway" type="radio" value="4063663">
    <label for="gateway_4063663">PagSeguro</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="payment-method" id="gateway_4068219" name="gateway" type="radio" value="4068219">
    <label for="gateway_4068219">Cash on Delivery (COD)</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I need to replace the label of gateway_4063663 for an image called 'icon_1.gif' but I have only access with CSS3.
Is there a way to replace the label... or set an backgroud image?

I'm using a css like

```
#payment-methods li #gateway_4063663 label { background: url('icon_1.gif'); }
```

but nothing happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

As I mentioned, my xpath was wrong... the correct path is

```
    #payment-methods li label[for="gateway_4063663"] {
        content: url('pic_1.gif')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, wrap around a `<div>` tag, and change the background of `<div>`

```
<div class="TEST">
   <label for="gateway_4063663">PagSeguro</label>
</div>
```

Change the background image for `<div>` and set the opacity for label to 0.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not change the html... and have no access to javascript...
I need to interact with an ecommerce checkout page, which is almost completely closed, only with the CSS exposed to apply themes. The page only list the payment gateways as text, and I need to transform it to a more fancy style...

Comment: How can I access the label? Because I think that the path is incorrect, because when I try the path `#payment-methods li #gateway_4063663 label` I can't change nothing... neihter the color...

Comment: I just check ur replies, glad that you found the answer.